# Show child elements into parent by changing its class through jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

May be I can't express my problem in my post title but here it is..

Suppose I have a parent div element and no. of child elements. All the child elements are set display:none, and I have two `<a>` elements which is next and previous button. I have given the first child elements class active. When the page will be loaded, jQuery will check if the first child's visibility set to visible then it will disable the back button. But my question is when I click on next button how to set the class "active" to next one respectively, **and when it will reach the last child, the next button automatically hide.**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="active">First child</div>
    <div>Second child</div>
    <div>Thirdchild</div>
</div>

<a href="" id="back">Back</a>
<a href="" id="next">Next</a>
```

Css:

```
.main{
    display: none;
}

.main.active{
    display: block;
}
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function () {

        if($('.main div').first().hasClass('active')){
            $("#back").hide();
        }

        /* Next previous **/
        $("#next").click(function(e) {


        });

        $("#back").click(function(e) {


        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through unordered list with jquery prev next buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613965/looping-through-unordered-list-with-jquery-prev-next-buttons)

Comment: see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x2p9yoke/3/

Comment: when class active on last child, the next button shows. If again click on next button then it disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the js. just the functions are shown.

```
$("#next").click(function(e) {

        var ind = 0;

       $('.main div').each(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('active'))
            {
               ind = $(this).index()+2;
            }
       });
       $('.main div').removeClass('active');
       $('.main div:nth-child('+ind+')').addClass('active');
       $("#back").show();
       if($('.main div').last().hasClass('active')){
        $("#next").hide();
    }


    });

    $("#back").click(function(e) {
         $("#next").show();
        var ind = 0;

       $('.main div').each(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('active'))
            {
               ind = $(this).index();

            }
       });
       if(ind==1)
       $('#back').hide();
       $('.main div').removeClass('active');
       $('.main div:nth-child('+ind+')').addClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: @AshisBiswas did you even check the other solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You can check if active has next sibling, if yes then remove class from existing and add to next. else add class active to first div element in `.main` div element and vice versa logic goes for back button:

```js
$(function(){
$("#next").click(function(e) {
  var activeelement = $('.active');
  if(activeelement.next().length)
    activeelement.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
  else
    activeelement.removeClass('active').closest('.main').find('> div:first').addClass('active');
 });

$("#back").click(function(e) {
  var activeelement = $('.active');
  if(activeelement.prev().length)
activeelement.removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
  else
activeelement.removeClass('active').closest('.main').find('> div:last').addClass('active');
 });
});
```

```css
.main div{
    display: none;
}

.main .active{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="active">First child</div>
    <div>Second child</div>
    <div>Thirdchild</div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="back">Back</a>
<a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
```

Comment: But how to disable next button when it moves to last element

Comment: @AshisBiswas: you can not disable anchor tag directly.  you will have to use one of the solution from http://techniblogic.com/how-to-disable-anchor-tag-href-links-by-html-css-javascript/#

Comment: Sorry I mean hide. So user cant further click on next button when he/she already on last item or last child.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
 $("#next").click(function(e) {
 $("#back").show();
   if (!$(".active").next().length) {
     $(this).hide()
   }
   $(".active").next().addClass("active").prev().removeClass("active");
 });
 $("#back").click(function(e) {
  $("#next").show();
   if (!$(".active").prev().length) {
     $(this).hide()
   }
   $(".active").prev().addClass("active").next().removeClass("active");
 });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x2p9yoke/3/)

Get the the next element using `.next()`.

Comment: will break for last element for next and first element in prev.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar no, it wont.

Comment: clicking on next when active is at last wont set active on first element. looping should be there right?

Comment: but OP didnt mention about the looping in question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('document').ready(function () {

    if($('.main div').first().hasClass('active')){
        $("#back").hide();
    }

    /* Next previous **/
    $("#next").click(function(e) {
        if($('.main div').hasClass('active)){
           $(this).removeClass('active')
           $(this).next().addClass('active')

    });

    $("#back").click(function(e) {


    });

});
```